# I want to change the list so that it has the same value twice in a row

Tags: python, list, seaborn

I want to change the list so that it has the same value twice in a row.
As you can see below, there is currently no coverage in the RGB values. I would like to have two consecutive RGB values that are the same, but I don't know how.
I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to do this.

```
import seaborn as sns

def get_colorpalette(colorpalette, file_number):
    palette = sns.color_palette(
        colorpalette, file_number)
    rgb = ['rgb({},{},{})'.format(*[x*256 for x in rgb])
           for rgb in palette]
    return rgb
```

```
['rgb(220.16,95.0272,87.03999999999999)',
 'rgb(220.16,167.6381090909091,87.03999999999999)',
 'rgb(200.0709818181818,220.16,87.03999999999999)',
 'rgb(127.46007272727276,220.16,87.03999999999999)',
 'rgb(87.03999999999999,220.16,119.23083636363639)',
  ・
  ・
  ・
```

```
['rgb(220.16,95.0272,87.03999999999999)',
 'rgb(220.16,95.0272,87.03999999999999)',
 'rgb(220.16,167.6381090909091,87.03999999999999)',
 'rgb(220.16,167.6381090909091,87.03999999999999)',
 'rgb(200.0709818181818,220.16,87.03999999999999)',
 'rgb(200.0709818181818,220.16,87.03999999999999)',
  ・
  ・
  ・
```

Comment: To be clear: you want to repeat *each* value in the input? Where you say "here is currently no coverage in the RGB values", I don't understand what you mean. What is "coverage" here?

Comment: Do you mean `rgb = [y for x in rgb for y in [x, x]]` ?

Comment: Or just `np.repeat(rgb, 2)`

Answer (score 1):

It can be easily done using a for-loop. I used characters as the elements since ultimately the elements in your list also are strings.

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
aa = []
for i in a:
    aa.append(i)
    aa.append(i)
aa
['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c']
```